# writing strings in qtable items

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qstring, qtablewidgetitem

i have a problem in writing strings in qtable item
i have made a table and set items in it and i want to get strings from user ( by lineEdit ) and then write them in a selected item. this is my code:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item[10][10];
.
.
.

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
item[i][j] = new QTableWidgetItem;
item[i][j]->setText(0);
ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, item[i][j]);}
.
.
.

int j = ui->tableWidget->currentColumn();
int i = ui->tableWidget->currentRow();
QString str = ui->formulaLineEdit->text();
ui->tableWidget->item(i,j)->setText( str );
```

and then it says this to me: project.exe exited with code -1073741819

what's wrong with this code?! ( if i remove the last line other parts work, the problem is here but i dont know what )

Answer (score 1):

Set the row and column count:

[void setRowCount(int rows)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html#rowCount-prop)
[void setColumnCount(int columns)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html#columnCount-prop)

(Edit: You must set it before setItems, else it will silently do nothing)

```
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(10);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(10);

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
  {
   ui->tableWidget->setItem( i, j, new QTableWidgetItem() );
  }
}

.
.

QString str = ui->formulaLineEdit->text();
// Get the item this way
int j = ui->tableWidget->currentColumn();
int i = ui->tableWidget->currentRow();
QTableWidgetItem *my_item = ui->tableWidget->item(i,j);
// Or
 QTableWidgetItem *my_item = ui->tableWidget->currentItem();
// Check it's not 0!!!
if (my_item)
  my_item->setText( str );
```

You should always **check** that ui->tableWidget->item(i,j) is returning something.

From docs:

> QTableWidgetItem * QTableWidget::item(int row, int column) const
>   Returns the item for the given row and column if one has been set;
>   **otherwise returns 0**.

And  accessing a null pointer crashes the program..

Some observations:

- Theres a [QTableWidgetItem * TableWidget::currentItem()
  const](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html#currentItem)
  method.  It could be of use, better than getting current row and
  column.  But check what it returns!
- Setting an item in a table gives ownership of that item to the table,
  that means, you dont have to keep that array of pointers, table will 
  take care of deleting the item when no needed